# Unsupported operand types when value is integer

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm getting this error when trying to add 2 to an integer. I am using the Codeigniter framework.

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in D:\wamp\www\application\libraries\Gen_images.php on line 180

Here is where its called:

```
// Now process the image
var_dump($this->upload->data('image_width'));
$this->gen_login->resize($file_name, $this->upload->data('image_width'), $this->upload->data('image_height'));
```

I get the error on `line 180` which is:

```
$config['width'] = $width + 2;
```

So I thought $width must be an array or string so I wouldn't be able to add to it, but the `var dump` shows this:

```
array
  'file_name' => string 'genyx_1341414096.jpg' (length=20)
  'file_type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
  'file_path' => string 'D:/wamp/www/beer/uploads/' (length=25)
  'full_path' => string 'D:/wamp/www/beer/uploads/genyx_1341414096.jpg' (length=45)
  'raw_name' => string 'genyx_1341414096' (length=16)
  'orig_name' => string 'genyx_1341414096.jpg' (length=20)
  'client_name' => string '294207_177080222375077_100002193022560_361510_991268937_s.jpg' (length=61)
  'file_ext' => string '.jpg' (length=4)
  'file_size' => float 55.85
  'is_image' => boolean true
  'image_width' => int 720
  'image_height' => int 479
  'image_type' => string 'jpeg' (length=4)
  'image_size_str' => string 'width="720" height="479"' (length=24)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried to cast $width like (int) $width?

Comment: What's the result of `var_dump($witdh)`?

Comment: var_dump($width); seems to give exactly the same as the other var_dump...

Comment: But why does var_dumping the'image_width' give the whole lot?

Answer (score 0):

There is no variable named `$width` in any of your code shown above...

`$width` is most definitely not a string. I can guarantee it.

Comment: It is passed into the function: public function resize($oldFile, $width, $height)